# How do you evaluate a certain part of an array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays

```
turns = [4, 6, 2, 8, 1, 9, 5, 5, 3, 7, 6, 8, 2, 4]
turns.append([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4])
turns.append([4, 6, 2, 8, 1, 9, 6, 5, 3, 7, 6, 8, 2, 4]) 
turns.append([0, 0, 26, 24, 3, 7, 5, 4, 25, 25, 21, 21, 21, 21])
turns.append([0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 3, 8, 2, 0, 0, 29, 29, 29, 29])
turns.append([0, 0, 0, 0, 26, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

arrayValue = turns[j][i]
    if arrayValue == turnCurrently:
```

```
Error Message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/a45d32f947055690c690d94f88/TicTacToe", line 183, in <module>
    arrayValue = turns[j][i]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

My question is essentially, I want to test if `turns[j][i]` is equal to `turnCurrently` but I keep running into this subscriptable problem, I haven't been able to find this answered anywhere I think that this is a very important question.  Thanks in advance,
Richard

Comment: Are you sure you want `turns` in this form? You create a plain list in the beginning, then append new lists to it, so it looks almost like 2D, but not quite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It often helps a lot to print out the content of your variables to see what it happening:

```
>>> turns
[4, 6, 2, 8, 1, 9, 5, 5, 3, 7, 6, 8, 2, 4, [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4], [0, 0, 26, 24, 3, 7, 5, 4, 25, 25, 21, 21, 21, 21], [0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 3, 8, 2, 0, 0, 29, 29, 29, 29], [0, 0, 0, 0, 26, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

As you can see, the first few elements of that list are simple integers, but not a list of ints. So when `j` is small, it will select an `int` and try to apply `[i]` on it – which fails.

The solution in this case is to put the first elements into an extra list:

```
turns = [[4, 6, 2, 8, 1, 9, 5, 5, 3, 7, 6, 8, 2, 4]]
turns.append( … )
```

Another way would be to initialize your list as an empty list, and append the first sub-list as well:

```
turns = []
turns.append([4, 6, 2, 8, 1, 9, 5, 5, 3, 7, 6, 8, 2, 4])
turns.append( … )
```

Comment: Really helpful too, that identified the problem...  THANKS

Answer (score 6):

Try this for building a two-dimensional array (a "matrix") of turns:

```
turns = [[4, 6, 2, 8, 1, 9, 5, 5, 3, 7, 6, 8, 2, 4]]
turns.append([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4])
turns.append([4, 6, 2, 8, 1, 9, 6, 5, 3, 7, 6, 8, 2, 4]) 
turns.append([0, 0, 26, 24, 3, 7, 5, 4, 25, 25, 21, 21, 21, 21])
turns.append([0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 3, 8, 2, 0, 0, 29, 29, 29, 29])
turns.append([0, 0, 0, 0, 26, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Or simply this:

```
turns = [[4, 6, 2, 8, 1, 9, 5, 5, 3, 7, 6, 8, 2, 4],
         [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
         [4, 6, 2, 8, 1, 9, 6, 5, 3, 7, 6, 8, 2, 4],
         [0, 0, 26, 24, 3, 7, 5, 4, 25, 25, 21, 21, 21, 21],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 3, 8, 2, 0, 0, 29, 29, 29, 29],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 26, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

As you can see, a matrix is nothing more than a list of lists. You weren't building a matrix in the first place - the first row *has* to be a list too.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped, it fixed the problem, I would have never thought of the beginning being ints and the later pars being lists.  THANKS SO MUCH!!

Comment: @user1434957 if this answer was helpful for you, please accept it as correct (click the check mark to its left)

Answer (score 2):

You array have a strange layout. The first 14 elements are integers, then follows a couple of other arrays.

So what you basically have is this:

```
[4, 6, 2, ..., 2, 4, [1, 1, 2, ...], [4, 6, ...], ...]
```

You may solve this by changing the first assignment to:

```
turns = [[4, 6, 2, 8, 1, 9, 5, 5, 3, 7, 6, 8, 2, 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

change `turns = [4, 6, 2, 8, 1, 9, 5, 5, 3, 7, 6, 8, 2, 4]` to

```
turns = [[4, 6, 2, 8, 1, 9, 5, 5, 3, 7, 6, 8, 2, 4]]
```

Comment: if you think the answer is useful give an upvote on my answer and accept it